# Modify SQLite backing store in core data managed ios app that's live

Tags: iphone, core-data, sqlite

I need help figuring out how I can correct mistakes in my SQLite database that's managed by core data.  I want to change the data in 1 table but im not sure how to accomplish this.  The app is live and users store information in a separate table so I can't delete it.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you have to change a data model (graph/schema) of your database?

Comment: I don't need to change the model, just the data contained in the SQLite database

Comment: The obvious answer is to look up the data, change it, and save the new values. Which part are you not clear on?

Comment: I guess the wish is to change it for all the users... Well, an app update (new version) should be the only way around, unless you have a client app and have a possibility to update your database from the server responses

Comment: Yes, I have to change the data during the first run of the update.  The only way I know of is making a custom mapping model. Im familiar with lightweight migration where core data can infer the schema changes but don't know how to correct the data on the fly using a mapping model. I know how to make every value for 1 attribute the same but now sure how to each individual entries.  Ex., if the first 5 rows have different numeric values and I need to change each one to a different number, how would I do this?

Comment: Tom, I was unclear about how to execute the data change and had someone help me by making an SQLite access class. Now during launch I compare the users DB version to the one I updated and if they arent up to date then the access class runs SQL statements to replace, modify or add data.